# Prove or disprove a proposition on Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions

Let $f(x) = \sum_{k\geq 0} a_kx^k$ be a real analytic function, converging on $-R < x < R$, whose $n^{th}$ Taylor polynomial is $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$.  If there exist $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and a sequence $\epsilon_n$ of values in $(0, R)$ such that $f_n > 0$ on $x\in(0, \epsilon_n)$ for $n\geq N$, then there exists $\epsilon\in(0,R)$ such that $f > 0$ on $x\in(0,\epsilon)$.

Is this statement true or false?  If true, can it be strengthened?  If false, is a weaker version true?

Edit: the statement is *true* provided that no subsequence of $\epsilon_n$ has limit 0.  Certainly $f(x)\geq 0$ on $x\in\left(0,\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\epsilon_n\right)$ by definition of convergence.  Moreover, since $f$ is analytic, by the coincidence theorem for analytic functions there can be no sequence $x_n\rightarrow 0$ such that $f(x_n) = 0$; otherwise $f\equiv 0$, contradicting the hypothesis.  So a suitable $\epsilon > 0$ must exist.

I still need to figure out what happens if a subsequence of $\epsilon_n$ approaches $0$.

Comment: A way to approach this is to argue about the sign of the first nonzero coefficient (assuming that $f(0) = 0$. If $f(0) > 0$ then use continuity at $0$). Do you know any theorems that bound the magnitude of the remainder term $f - f_n$?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Right, the question is not so interesting if $f(0)\neq 0$.  Also, thanks for catching the mixup (now fixed).

Answer (score 3):

The statement is **true**.

If $f(0) > 0$ then this follows by continuity.  Otherwise $f(x)=x^kg(x)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and real analytic $g(x)$ such that $g(0)\neq 0$.  Since the lowest-order nonzero derivative of $f$ at $x = 0$ must be strictly positive, it follows that $g(0) > 0$, so that by continuity $f(x) > 0$ for small $x > 0$.